# Need Regex pattern for split by ; and not with in []

Tags: regex

I got a string like "Save Action; Changed From[] To[test; more test]; Changed From[testing; more testing] To[good]"

I have to split the string by ';'. But it should ignore ';' with in the []. Can some one give me a Regex pattern for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on language/regex flavor you could use:

```
;(?![^\[]*\])
```

Comment: Very nice. My initial thought was that this couldn't be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about regexes, but this problem would probably be more easily and clearly solved by doing it in several steps (split by ;, then rejoin adjacent groups with unbalanced brackets), or as a simple state-machine.